# Issues with a button ID in js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to coding and am enrolled in a boot camp. I am having issues when my assignment

```js
//  quiz questions/choices/answerts variable
var quizQuestions = [ 
  {
    question: "What is an array?",
    answers: [
        "A single variable that stores multiple events",
        "It is a feature",
        "A button",
        "IDK",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "A single variable that stores multiple events",
},
{
  question: "What are the two values of a Boolean?",
  answers: [
       "Yes and No",
       "Now and later",
       "True and False",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "True and False",
},
{
  question: "What is a string?",
  answers: [
       "It is a shoelace ",
       "Stores and manipulates text",
       "A Guitar note",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "Stores and manipulates text",
},
{
  questions: "What does console.log do",
  answers: [
       "Creates an argument",
       "Creates an pnject",
       "Writes a message to the console",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "Writes a message to the console",
},
{
  questions: "What is a function?",
  answers: [
       "A building block in JS",
       "An expression",
       "A debugger",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "A building block in JS",
}
];
// variables for targeting html elements/atrrtibutes
var timerEl = document.getElementById('countdownTimer');
var startBtnEl = document.getElementById("startTimer");
var startScreen = document.getElementById('startScreen');
var choices = document.getElementById("choices");
var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
var quizArea = document.getElementById('quizArea');
var questArea = document.getElementById('questions');
var results = document.getElementById('endDiv');

// quiz start score of 0 
var score = 0;
// start on first question
var currentQuestion = 0

// timer ***change back to 15sec***
var timeLeft = 2;
var holdTime = 0;

var btn;

function checkAnswer(){
  // console.log('test', this.value);
  var choice = this.value;
  var correctAn = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer;
  if(choice === correctAn ){
    score++;
    alert('Correct')  
  } else{
    alert('Incorrect')
  }
  currentQuestion++;
  
  startQuiz();

  alert("You got " + score + '/' + quizQuestions.length);
}


// start quiz function 
function startQuiz () {

 //render question
  var quest = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
  questArea.textContent = quest;
  // console.log(quest);

 //render choices as buttons
 var options = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].answers;
//  console.log('currentQuestion = ', currentQuestion);
//  console.log('options = ', options);

// console.log(options.length);

 for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
   btn = document.createElement('button');
   btn.value = options[i];
   btn.textContent = options[i];
  //  console.error(options[i]);
   btn.onclick = checkAnswer;
   choices.appendChild(btn);
  }
 //     -- create a button
 //     --assign it value
 //     --assign it context
 //     --assign it an onclick function
 //         ..check if user answered correctly or not
  
};

// timer function
startBtnEl.addEventListener("click", function(){

  //      --hide start screen
startScreen.className = 'hide';
//      --show quizArea
quizArea.className = 'show';

  startQuiz();


  if (holdTime === 0) {
    holdTime = setInterval(function() {
      timeLeft--;
      holdTime.textContent = "You have " + timeLeft;
      timerEl.textContent = timeLeft

      if (timeLeft < 0) {
        timerEl.textContent = '';
        clearInterval(holdTime);
        //timesUp();
        alert("You have ran out of time!");
      }
    }, 1000);
    
  }
})

function results () {
} 

// at the bottom should be a click event function that creates a form for the person completing the quiz
// // the form consist of if else conditionals and a var that creates a score total. It wouls be written out in this form:


// addEventListener("click", function() {
//   var info = createInput.value;

//   if (info === null) {
//     console.log(info);
//   } 

//   var totalScore = JSON.parse(---)
// }
```

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  
  .container {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #247BA0;
    color: white;
  }

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Coding Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <header>
    <h1 class="page-title">Lets test your knowledge on Javascript!</h1>
</header> 
<!-- Quiz container -->
    <div id="container">

        <!-- Start Div -->
        <div id='startScreen' class='show'>
            <!-- Explation of app -->
             <h2>Click "Start" when you are ready to begin!</h2>
          <button id="startTimer">Start</button>
        </div>

        <!-- //QUIZ AREA -->

        <div id='quizArea' class='hide'>
             <p>Timer:<span id="countdownTimer"></span></p>
            <h2 id='questions'></h2>
            <div id='choices'></div>
        </div>

        <!-- End Screen -->
        <div id='endDiv' class='hide'>
            <h2>END RESULT</h2>
            <button id="results">Results</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

which is creating a quiz manipulating the DOM. My issue is when the user selects their choice, the questions rotate out however the choices do not. The prev choices stay and the ones just add on. So at the end I am left with 16 choice buttons. Please help!

Comment: Hide each quiz option when the question number changes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, add doc....innerHTML = ''

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the previous option informations before inserting the new button options.

`choices.textContent = ""; // this will clear the previous information`

```
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
   btn = document.createElement('button');
   btn.value = options[i];
   btn.textContent = options[i];
   //  console.error(options[i]);
   btn.onclick = checkAnswer;
   choices.appendChild(btn);
 }
```

```js
//  quiz questions/choices/answerts variable
var quizQuestions = [ 
  {
    question: "What is an array?",
    answers: [
        "A single variable that stores multiple events",
        "It is a feature",
        "A button",
        "IDK",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "A single variable that stores multiple events",
},
{
  question: "What are the two values of a Boolean?",
  answers: [
       "Yes and No",
       "Now and later",
       "True and False",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "True and False",
},
{
  question: "What is a string?",
  answers: [
       "It is a shoelace ",
       "Stores and manipulates text",
       "A Guitar note",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "Stores and manipulates text",
},
{
  questions: "What does console.log do",
  answers: [
       "Creates an argument",
       "Creates an pnject",
       "Writes a message to the console",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "Writes a message to the console",
},
{
  questions: "What is a function?",
  answers: [
       "A building block in JS",
       "An expression",
       "A debugger",
       "IDK",
  ],
  correctAnswer: "A building block in JS",
}
];
// variables for targeting html elements/atrrtibutes
var timerEl = document.getElementById('countdownTimer');
var startBtnEl = document.getElementById("startTimer");
var startScreen = document.getElementById('startScreen');
var choices = document.getElementById("choices");
var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
var quizArea = document.getElementById('quizArea');
var questArea = document.getElementById('questions');
var results = document.getElementById('endDiv');

// quiz start score of 0 
var score = 0;
// start on first question
var currentQuestion = 0

// timer ***change back to 15sec***
var timeLeft = 2;
var holdTime = 0;

var btn;

function checkAnswer(){
  // console.log('test', this.value);
  var choice = this.value;
  var correctAn = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer;
  if(choice === correctAn ){
    score++;
    alert('Correct')  
  } else{
    alert('Incorrect')
  }
  currentQuestion++;
  
  startQuiz();

  alert("You got " + score + '/' + quizQuestions.length);
}


// start quiz function 
function startQuiz () {

 //render question
  var quest = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
  questArea.textContent = quest;
  // console.log(quest);

 //render choices as buttons
 var options = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].answers;
 
//  console.log('currentQuestion = ', currentQuestion);
//  console.log('options = ', options);

// console.log(options.length);
 choices.textContent = "";
 for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
   btn = document.createElement('button');
   btn.value = options[i];
   btn.textContent = options[i];
  //  console.error(options[i]);
   btn.onclick = checkAnswer;
   choices.appendChild(btn);
  }
 //     -- create a button
 //     --assign it value
 //     --assign it context
 //     --assign it an onclick function
 //         ..check if user answered correctly or not
  
};

// timer function
startBtnEl.addEventListener("click", function(){

  //      --hide start screen
startScreen.className = 'hide';
//      --show quizArea
quizArea.className = 'show';

  startQuiz();


  if (holdTime === 0) {
    holdTime = setInterval(function() {
      timeLeft--;
      holdTime.textContent = "You have " + timeLeft;
      timerEl.textContent = timeLeft

      if (timeLeft < 0) {
        timerEl.textContent = '';
        clearInterval(holdTime);
        //timesUp();
        alert("You have ran out of time!");
      }
    }, 1000);
    
  }
})

function results () {
} 

// at the bottom should be a click event function that creates a form for the person completing the quiz
// // the form consist of if else conditionals and a var that creates a score total. It wouls be written out in this form:


// addEventListener("click", function() {
//   var info = createInput.value;

//   if (info === null) {
//     console.log(info);
//   } 

//   var totalScore = JSON.parse(---)
// }
```

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  
  .container {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #247BA0;
    color: white;
  }

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Coding Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <header>
    <h1 class="page-title">Lets test your knowledge on Javascript!</h1>
</header> 
<!-- Quiz container -->
    <div id="container">

        <!-- Start Div -->
        <div id='startScreen' class='show'>
            <!-- Explation of app -->
             <h2>Click "Start" when you are ready to begin!</h2>
          <button id="startTimer">Start</button>
        </div>

        <!-- //QUIZ AREA -->

        <div id='quizArea' class='hide'>
             <p>Timer:<span id="countdownTimer"></span></p>
            <h2 id='questions'></h2>
            <div id='choices'></div>
        </div>

        <!-- End Screen -->
        <div id='endDiv' class='hide'>
            <h2>END RESULT</h2>
            <button id="results">Results</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```